# how to generate a bidimensional array with different "branch" lengths very fast

Tags: delphi, dynamic-arrays

I am a Delphi programmer.
In a program I have to generate bidimensional arrays with different "branch" lengths.
They are very big and the operation takes a few seconds (annoying).

For example:

```
var a: array of array of Word;
  i: Integer;

begin
   SetLength(a, 5000000);
   for i := 0 to 4999999 do
      SetLength(a[i], Diff_Values);
end;
```

I am aware of the command SetLength(a, dim1, dim2) but is not applicable. Not even setting a min value (> 0) for dim2 and continuing from there because min of dim2 is 0 (some "branches" can be empty).

So, is there a way to make it fast? Not just by 5..10% but really FAST...

Thank you.

Comment: In what range is `length(a[i])`?

Comment: can the _branch length_ vary during the operation or not?

Comment: Is a list (TList) of TLists more suitable for you than arrays?

Comment: could you tell us more about the problem that leads to this data structure?

Comment: There is no known minimum branch length, but is there a known maximum? If so, is max * 500000 a feasible allocation?

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand Range is 0..10. @jachguate Most of the times the branch lengths it will not vary; if there is a solution I will try to modify the code so they will not vary. @Roman Yankovsky I can't use TList, it has to be array. @David Heffernan I'm really sorry, it's not my call, but I can't reveal much of my work in this moment. Maybe later. I hope you will understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Paul-Jan My technical english is not 100%, could you please explain what you're trying to say..?

Comment: @PeterL, if your "branches" are at most 11 words, take a good look at my answer. Your numbers are tiny! And why can't you use TList? Why is array a requirement?

Comment: @Cosmin Prund I am looking but I try to understand the answers one at a time, and now I'm at David's. Array is a requirement because of the way data is used after.

Comment: @peter TList is an array

Comment: @David I know but I meant that it has to be a simple array not some class, sorry for not being more precise.

Comment: @PeterL But you can set it up so that it you still access it with a[r,c] efficiently.

Comment: @PeterL, you came here with a problem: if you refuse all help because "it has to be an array" and "it can't be a class" and "can't use lazy initialization"... you're simply refusing all alternative solutions. There are no magic bullets. If you don't change anything, you'll be stuck with the same (poorly) performing solution.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund It's not up to me I have to consider how the data will be used. My question is about "bidimensional array" not other type of data. I don't refuse help, I'm just simply try to find a solution that will work in my program. If there isn't, I will just try to optimize something else. I didn't know that here at stackoverflow I have to accept solutions without saying why they will not work. Sorry, I will respond to the next answers only with "thank you".

Comment: @Peter We are just trying to understand your requirements. The more information we have, the better the advice we can give.

Answer (score 5):

When dealing with a large amount of data, there's a lot of work that has to be done, and this places a theoretical minimum on the amount of time it can be done in.

For each of 5 million iterations, you need to:

- Determine the size of the "branch" somehow
- Allocate a new array of the appropriate size from the memory manager
- Zero out all the memory used by the new array (SetLength does this for you automatically)

Step 1 is completely under your control and can possibly be optimized.  2 and 3, though, are about as fast as they're gonna get if you're using a modern version of Delphi.  (If you're on an old version, you might benefit from installing FastMM and FastCode, which can speed up these operations.)

The other thing you might do, if appropriate, is *lazy initialization*.  Instead of trying to allocate all 5 million arrays at once, just do the `SetLength(a, 5000000);` at first.  Then when you need to get at a "branch", first check if its length = 0.  If so, it hasn't been initialized, so initialize it to the proper length.  This doesn't save time overall, in fact it will take slightly longer in total, but it does spread out the initialization time so the user doesn't notice.

If your initialization is already as fast as it will get, and your situation is such that lazy initialization can't be used here, then you're basically out of luck.  That's the price of dealing with large amounts of data.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler Thank you for the suggestions. I already use Delphi 2008. But I can't use lazy initialization.

Comment: @PeterL: There is no Delphi 2008. Do you mean 2007 or 2009?  (Both have FastMM and FasCode in the RTL, though.)

Comment: @dthorpe LOL. You were too busy working on your own answer I guess.

Comment: @David Sorry, 2009. Typo. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your exact code, with a constant for `Diff_Values`, timed it using `GetTickCount()` for rudimentary timing. If `Diff_Values` is `186` it takes 1466 milliseconds, if `Diff_Values` is `187` it fails with `Out of Memory`. You know, `Out of Memory` means `Out of Address Space`, not really `Out of Memory`.

**In my opinion you're allocating so much data you run out of RAM and Windows starts paging**, that's why it's slow. On my system I've got enough RAM for the process to allocate as much as it wants; And it does, until it fails.

### Possible solutions

- The obvious one: Don't allocate that much!
- Figure out a way to allocate all data into one contiguous block of memory: helps with address space fragmentation. Similar to how a bi dimensional array with fixed size on the "branches" is allocated, but if your "branches" have different sizes, you'll need to figure a different mathematical formula, based on your data.
- Look into other data structures, possibly ones that cache on disk (to brake the 2Gb address space limit).

Comment: What I showed is just a example, in my program there are a few that fit in RAM. It's not slow because of the paging, I can assure you. And I can't allocate less.

Comment: @PeterL, using your code, on my machine, it's *fast*. You said sub-array sizes vary in the 0 to 10 range; I tested with Diff_Values = 10, it took 250ms. You said it takes "seconds" to allocate the arrays, 250ms in that case is a minimum of 75% improvement, possibly more. I didn't do anything special, I simply copy-pasted your code and replaced Diff_Values with 10. I don't run a super-computer, but I do have 8Gb ram.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Mason's points, here are some more ideas to consider:

If the branch lengths never change after they are allocated, and you have an upper bound on the total number of items that will be stored in the array across all branches, then you might be able to save some time by allocating one huge chunk of memory and divvying up the "branches" within that chunk yourself.  Your array would become a 1 dimensional array of pointers, and each entry in that array points to the start of the data for that branch.  You keep track of the "end" of the used space in your big block with a single pointer variable, and when you need to reserve space for a new "branch" you take the current "end" pointer value as the start of the new branch and increment the "end" pointer by the amount of space that branch requires.  Don't forget to round up to dword boundaries to avoid misalignment penalties.

This technique will require more use of pointers, but it offers the potential of eliminating all the heap allocation overhead, or at least replacing the general purpose heap allocation with a purpose-built very simple, very fast suballocator that matches your specific use pattern.  It should be faster to execute, but it will require more time to write and test.

This technique will also avoid heap fragmentation and reduces the releasing of all the memory to a single deallocation (instead of millions of separate allocations in your present model).

Another tip to consider:  If the first thing you always do with the each newly allocated array "branch" is assign data into every slot, then you can eliminate step 3 in Mason's example - you don't need to zero out the memory if all you're going to do is immediately assign real data into it.  This will cut your memory write operations by half.

Comment: Step 3 is taking place automatically as part of SetLength, and can't be skipped.  I was just explaining what's going on.

Comment: @Mason: It can be skipped if we don't use SetLength to allocate the array.

Comment: @David: you type faster. dammit!  ;>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can fit the entire data structure into a contiguous block of memory, you can do the allocation in one shot and then take over the indexing.

***Note**: Even if you can't fit the data into a single contiguous block of memory, you can still use this technique by allocating multiple large blocks and then piecing them together.*

First off form a helper array, `colIndex`, which is to contain the index of the first column of each row. Set the length of `colIndex` to `RowCount+1`. You build this by setting `colIndex[0] := 0` and then `colIndex[i+1] := colIndex[i] + ColCount[i]`. Do this in a for loop which runs up to and including `RowCount`. So, in the final entry, `colIndex[RowCount]`, you store the total number of elements.

Now set the length of a to be `colIndex[RowCount]`. This may take a little while, but it will be quicker than what you were doing before.

Now you need to write a couple of indexers.  Put them in a class or a record.

The getter looks like this:

```
 function GetItem(row, col: Integer): Word;
 begin
   Result := a[colIndex[row]+col];
 end;
```

The setter is obvious.  You can inline these access methods for increased performance.  Expose them as an indexed property for convenience to the object's clients.

You'll want to add some code to check for validity of `row` and `col`. You need to use `colIndex` for the latter. You can make this checking optional with `{$IFOPT R+}` if you want to mimic range checking for native indexing.

Of course, this is a total non-starter if you want to change any of your column counts after the initial instantiation!